# Storing a number in a given hex location in C

Tags: c, pointers

Let's assume that there is a function `store_at(int)` which is supposed to store the passed number in a given hexa location as shown below:

```
void store_at(int val)
{
int *ptr;
ptr = (int *)0x261;

// logic goes here

return;
}
```

How do we write logic to store val at the given Hex location (0x261 In this case)?

Does saying `*ptr = val;` work? I vaguely remember reading somewhere that this is not allowed in C.

Comment: Hummm... why would you want to poke memory at a location like that? That is a nice way to segfault or crash the code...

Comment: you can cast the pointer of being type int, then store the value by dereferencing

Comment: if your memory address is valid, then yes this will work. Note: I mean both physically *and* logically valid

Comment: Of course, **assuming** its valid, then that will work!

Comment: Can I know the reason as to why you want to do this? Am curious.

Comment: *ptr = val should be legal... as long as you've previously allocated an int's worth of memory at that address; otherwise it is undefined behavior.  However, this sort of code looks like a maintenance nightmare; there's probably a better way to achieve what you're trying to do...

Comment: And; this might be helpful when poking around, linux. Depending on what you are doing: $ setarch $(uname -p) --addr-no-randomize $SHELL

Answer (score 2):

`*ptr = val;` works. But you have to make sure this address is allocated and even more, accessible. Without knowing for what you are programming C, I could suggest some ways of prevention on accessing addresses you don't have permission. So it pretty much depends on the architecture and/or operational system you're using.

For example, in ATMEGA32 microcontroller, you don't have any limitation regarding the access of the main memory for it. You can read, write and execute code from/for it:

```
PORTB = 1;
// Knowing that PORTB is stored at 0x38, you can do the equivalent:
*((unsigned int *)0x0038) = 1;
```

But that's on embedded systems. Now if you want total access for a memory space (as long as it's in your application sandbox), you can use `VirtualProtect` for Windows and `mprotect` for Linux:

```
int val = 123;
DWORD oldprotection;

VirtualProtect((LPVOID)0x261, sizeof(int), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldprotection);

*(int *)0x261 = val;
```

And here is the types of protection you can use with it: [Memory Protection Constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366786.aspx).

And a [`mprotect`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mprotect.2.html) example:

```
int val = 123;

mprotect((const void *)(((int)(0x261) / PAGESIZE) * PAGESIZE), sizeof(int), PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ | PROT_EXEC);

*(int *)0x261 = val;
```

Note that this `mprotect` example is untested, you may need to increase the size for protection or some other things.

The division by `PAGESIZE` there is just a trick to align the address correctly. Also note that your address is invalid for Linux, as its division will lead to 0 if `PAGESIZE` is greater than it (the same as *"it will be"*).

---

According to the syntax for accessing a address using a pointer, all of these work:

```
*(int *)0x261 = val;

int *ptr = (int *)0x261;
*ptr = val;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, expression `*ptr = val` (and even more, `*(int *)0x261 = val;` ) is perfectly valid in C. But then you're facing technical limitations of runtime environments.

Modern operating systems usually run processes in a sandbox of virtual memory (so processes can't access and spoil memory of some other process) and technically the virtual memory of a process looks like a set of regions which you can access, some in readonly way, some does not allow executing code from here and so on. When you try to access non-available VM region, you'll get `SIGSEGV` on Unix-like systems or `Access Violation` error on Windows systems, the same for writing to a read-only memory region and trying to execute code in region where it's prohibited by operating system (for example, you can see virtual memory mappings for a linux process with pid  in `/proc/$PID/maps`.

Memory of a process is usually managed by the operating system (you get new memory from the heap using OS-provided functions like `malloc()`, `calloc()`; the stack memory regions are allocated by the OS at process startup), so in user-space programming you virtually never need to reference data by literal pointer.

Another possible environments are kernel-space or bare-metal C programs, where you have all the physical memory available to you, but still you must be aware of what you accessing (it may be ports, a gap in the physical memory, it may be reserved by hardware and so on). Programming such environments is an advanced topic and needs good C experience.